# Can I purge linux-modules-4.* and linux-modules-extra-4.* packages?

Tags: package-management, kernel, uninstall

I have a plenty of old config-file status *linux-modules-4.xxx* and *linux-modules-extra-4.xxx* (see the pictures). The 5.x version of the Linux kernel is already out.

When I do `wajig large` there was a plenty of old packages, can I remove all of these and only keep the 5.x versions?
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKvkq.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toDT7.png)